# How to rewrite and parse a single file with .js extension as php in Nginx

Tags: nginx

My request looks like this

```
domain.com/lib/browser/detect.js
```

Now internally I would like to serve `/lib/browser/detect.php`

My Nginx conf looks like this

```
location = /lib/browser/detect.js {
        try_files non-existent /lib/browser/detect.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*);
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Nginx forces my browser to download this file.

Comment: Is the browser downloading the source of `detect.php` or its generated content?

Comment: I think try_files will serve the actual php file if the path is good, instead of transferring control to the .php location block. You likely want to rewrite instead.

Comment: @RichardSmith It's downloading the source, so the php location handler does not get triggered

Comment: Does the URI `/lib/browser/detect.php` also download source when specified in the browser? BTW, there is nothing wrong with your `try_files` statement (except that *non-existent* is a bit of a fudge).

Comment: @RichardSmith No it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `rewrite` directive instead of `try_files` as that is meant to server static files only.

Something like this might do it:

```
location = /lib/browser/detect.js {
    rewrite .* /lib/browser/detect.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*);
    fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

The `rewrite` in this case can probably match on anything since it's already inside an exact match location block. You could also make the match in the `rewrite` directive and take it out of the location block and into the server block like I've done in my test here:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /var/www/;
  rewrite /detect.js /detect.php;
  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
```

This is otherwise default config from nginx and php-fpm packages on alpine linux.
Contents of fastcgi.conf file are:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the rewrite does not trigger the php location handler.

Comment: There must be some other detail not right, I tested this as working. I am adding details to the answer.

Comment: Indeed this works. Another problem was that the mime type was incorrect. Had to force it like `location = /lib/browser/detect.php { default_type application/javascript; }`

Answer (score 0):

The only way so far I found is this

```
location = /lib/browser/detect.js {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/lib/browser/detect.php;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO detect.php;
}
```